# EF Core async methods hang/deadlock after await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

Update: The issue was actually unrelated to async - my database was out of sync and the LINQ queries were failing. DSharpPlus discards caught exceptions so there was no indication of any problem. See my self-answer below for more details.

I am encountering a hang/deadlock while attempting to use the async methods of EF Core on .NET 5. This is in a console app (so no ASP.NET, WPF, or anything like that) but I am using the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) package to manage the application lifecycle. I am also using a 3rd party middleware [DSharpPlus](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus) which is responsible for dispatching work onto a thread pool, which is where I call into EF. Dependency injection is in use, configured via Host.CreateDefaultBuilder.

DSharpPlus is run asynchronously from an IHostedService (via a scoped DI wrapper - since hosted services must be singletons and DbContext is scoped). It dispatches events onto a thread pool (via Task.Run) after creating a new instance of the handler code from a fresh DI scope. The handler code calls into a newly created instance of an injected service, which finally calls into the DbContext (also a fresh instance).

This is more complex than I would like, but everything I've read suggests that it should work. Unfortunately, it breaks when I attempt to use EF. Any code using EF hangs as soon as it awaits, but the same code works when EF is stubbed out. This is the shortest/simplest transaction (reduced a bit for readability):

```
// This line is from DSharpPlus (not my code) but I'm including it for clarity.
// This line is called at end of a network event handler and exists only to dispatch the event to a thread pool (it immediately returns after this line)
// ExecuteCommandAsync is responsible for creating a new DI scope and fresh instance of the command handler, which contains the function below.
_ = Task.Run(async () => await this.ExecuteCommandAsync(ctx).ConfigureAwait(false));

// Called eventually by above code, inside a fresh object with a new DI scope
// _hydrationLeaderboard, _hydrationOptions, and _logger are injected each time.
// _logger is a standard .NET ILogger instance.
public async Task ScoresCommand(CommandContext ctx)
{
    using (_logger.BeginScope($"CmdScores.ScoresCommand@{ctx.Message.Id.ToString()}"))
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Requested by [{user}]", ctx.User);
        
        // This never returns
        var leaderboard = await _hydrationLeaderboard.GetLeaderboard(_hydrationOptions.LeaderboardSize);
    
        // ** snipped **
    }
}

// Called by above code
// _selfcareDb is new DbContext instance from DI
public Task<List<HydrationLeaderboardEntry>> GetLeaderboard(int top = 3)
{
    // This never returns. The original has additional LINQ, but it still fails like this too.
    // It also fails if method is async/await
    return _selfcareDb.UserScores
        .Select((us, idx) => new HydrationLeaderboardEntry(
            // **Snip**, just copying properties from DB entity to service entity
        )
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

I think I've ruled out the usual suspects for async hangs - I am not using .Wait, .GetResult, or any other calls like that. I don't have any synchronous code mixed in (unless I missed it). I have made sure that a unique DbContext instance is injected for each task. As a test, I removed all of the EF code and replaced it with an in-memory Dictionary. This worked fine. I even reviewed the code of DSharpPlus and didn't see anything suspicious.

**Many apologies if I've made an obvious mistake somewhere!** This is my first project using async EF and I'm still relatively new to async/await generally. I would be happy to share the full code of this project if that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the database that I'm using is Sqlite.

UPDATE: The Task.Run call does not seem to be the issue. The calls to EF still hang even when using an alternate event dispatch that uses entirely async/await within a single thread.

Comment: Not sure why you are *offloading* here `_ = Task.Run(async () => await this`, I have no idea about Discord or the API, but its not a good look on any day. There is nothing else in the code that looks outwardly suspicious I can see, and nothing that would point to the classic deadlock problem. Personally id remove that `Task.Run` on principle, then start pulling/commenting out strategic code until it works

Comment: That code is from DSharpPlus. I _think_ it does that because it uses a single network thread that shouldn't block. At least that's what I understood from the documentation. I can't easily change how that function works but I might be able to determine if it is the problem by calling EF from one of the other event handlers that doesn't offload.

Comment: The problem still occurs with that line avoided, unfortunately. I traced the new flow from Main to EF (through DSharpPlus) and unless I missed something, it uses only async/await. No calls to Task, GetAwaiter, Result, etc that I can see.

Comment: `.ConfigureAwait(false);`?

Comment: Does the EF core code work without DSharpPlus? I am wondering if you have misconfigured the database connection and, somehow, that exception is being swallowed by DSharpPlus?

Comment: @SimplyGed That was the issue. I figured it out by luck when I made a mistake with some unrelated code and realized that the execution was stopping before it even reached EF. I believe DSharpPlus logs caught exceptions at debug level so they were filtered out by my log settings. Lesson learned: do my own exception logging!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DB error! I messed up my EF migrations so the database was empty, which obviously throws an exception. Somewhere along the way the exceptions were swallowed up and hidden. I fixed the DB errors and now everything works.

I also added a simple try/catch block to each command handlers and now I'm getting output whenever there are errors.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` , ConfigureAwait with false means you are not waitind the task to complete, I really suggest you to read [this blog](https://dev.to/noseratio/why-i-no-longer-use-configureawait-false-3pne#potential-remedy-for-deadlocks)

Comment: See my answer - it was a database error but the exceptions were being hidden. The ConfigureAwait is a snippet from code within DSharpPlus, not my own.

Comment: That's not what `ConfigureAwait(false)` means, though.

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) is about not returning back to the synchronization context when an awaiter completes.

It's about performance, not deadlocks.

That blog post is wrong!